# Query not working1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hey all I am trying to select data from three different tables based on the data found. It's not working. I am trying to display the selected in a grid-view. Any ideas?

```
 SELECT BossID, Status, CouponNumber, FK_PrizeID, FK_WinnerID 
 FROM BountyPrizes 
 union  
 select PrizeName from Prizes where PrizeID=FK_PrizeID  
 union  
 select FirstName, LastName, DOB from Players where PlayerID=FK_WinnerID
```

Error:
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'FK_PrizeID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid column name 'FK_WinnerID'.

Comment: You should be joining not unioning.

Comment: Please [edit] your subject line to make it more meaningful. "Query not working1" is not going to be of any use to anyone searching here in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Joins are where you want to take more from other tables. Unions are where you want to take 2 congruent tables and show the combined result

Here is the code you need:

```
SELECT BossID, Status, CouponNumber, FK_PrizeID, FK_WinnerID 
FROM BountyPrizes  
JOIN Prizes ON PrizeID=FK_PrizeID  
JOIN Players ON PlayerID=FK_WinnerID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT BossID, Status, CouponNumber, FK_PrizeID, FK_WinnerID, PrizeName, 
  FirstName, LastName, DOB 
FROM BountyPrizes, Prizes, Players
WHERE Prizes.PrizeID=BountyPrizes.FK_PrizeID 
  AND Players.PlayerID=BountyPrizes.FK_WinnerID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need JOIN:

```
SELECT T1.BossID, 
       T1.Status, 
       T1.CouponNumber, 
       T1.FK_PrizeID, 
       T1.FK_WinnerID,
       T2.PrizeName ,
       T3.FirstName, 
       T3.LastName, 
       T3.DOB
FROM   BountyPrizes T1
       LEFT JOIN Prizes T2
           ON T2.PrizeID=T1.FK_PrizeID
       LEFT JOIN Players T3
           ON T3.PlayerID=T1.FK_WinnerID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT BossID, Status, CouponNumber, FK_PrizeID, FK_WinnerID, Prizes.*, Players.*
FROM BountyPrizes 
JOIN Prizes on PrizeID=FK_PrizeID  
JOIN Players on PlayerID=FK_WinnerID
```